# BIOS shows zombies boot options

Tags: boot, bios

I installed Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows 10 some time ago, then I didn't need it any more and so I cleared the partitions where it was installed, but now I'm noticing that the boot still shows, among the boot options, entries referring to Ubuntu. How can I put order and clean the remains of Ubuntu? I saw the "Delete Boot Option" in the boot, will it clean properly the remains or will it just don't show the option any more, but leaving the GPT(?) dirty? Or the only remain is that entry in the boot options?

Pics:
[image: Boot options]

[image: Actual partitions status]

Comment: 'Delete boot option' should do the trick

Comment: Did you try looking at the options for `Delete boot option`?

Comment: Yes I did, it makes me delete the entry, but I wanted to clear every remain of Ubuntu and I don't know if the entries are the only one or a symptom indicanting the presence of other remains. In this case I would like to resolve the whole problem and not just to clear a symptom.